# Invoke-Command running as domain admin - remove certificate from other users Personal cert store?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to remove a given user's comm certificate in the *personal cert store*.

The issue is that in order to connect, I need to run `Invoke` under **admin context**, meaning if I run `certutil` commands... I get my admin accounts store, and not the user I'm trying to remove certs for.

I *could* remove the cert from the users `appdata\roaming\microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates` directory, but the issue there is I'd need a way to verify the `SHA1 hash` to ensure I'm only removing the one cert I need to.

In order to verify this hash, I think I'd still need to check in `certutil` which loops back to the original issue!

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use Group Policy to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately at my current company I do not have access to modify group policy nor would it really be appropriate for this particular application anyway.

Comment: Editing multiple users certificates is definitely best administered by GP. But  if you need to do a script in the user context, then the standard workarounds to get there are Scheduled Task, Start up script, or Run Once registry. So your invoke would just set up the job to run as the user.